# how to find a particular entry from json store using id/name

Tags: javascript, json

how to find a particular entry from json store using id/name? using javascript function

for eg:

```
var products=[{
    "productId": 101,
    "productName": "Nilkamal Shoe Rack",
    "productPrice": 2223,
    "productOriginalPrice": 2470,
    "productDiscount": "20 %",
    "productColor": "Sandy Brown",
    "productSpecifications": [{
        "Brand": "Nilakamal",
        "Type": "Shoe Rack",
        "Material": "Polypropylene"
    }],
    "productServices": ["Installation and Demo not Required", "10 Days Replacement"]
},

{
    "productId": 102,
    "productName": "Seagate Backup Plus Slim 1TB wired external hard disk",
    "productPrice": 3899,
    "productOriginalPrice": 7450,
    "productDiscount": "47 %",
    "productColor": "White",
    "productSpecifications": [{
        "Brand": "Seagate",
        "Type": "External Hard Disk",
        "Capacity": "1 TB",
        "Connectivity": "USB 3.0",
        "Ports": "1 Port"
    }],
    "productServices": ["3 years warranty", "10 Days Replacement"]
}]
```

How can I find all the details of one of the following product using id/name?

Comment: That's not a JSON store.  At that point it's a javascript array comprised of objects.  So you probably are wanting to filter your array of objects by a particular ID and then access the other attributes of that filtered object.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use array.find like this

```
 var myObj = products.find(obj => obj.productId == 102);
 console.log(myObj);
```

if you want function then

```
function getObjbyId(id){
     var myObj = products.find(obj => obj.productId == id);
     return myObj;
}
```

Comment: [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is awesome!  But note that it's not supported in IE.  It is supported in Edge, however.  Still, it is very cool.  OP may not need IE support, but it's still good to mention potential compatibility issue.